# Strange feature in vue-devtools

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm exploring Vue and Vue-devtools and have strange feature, screenshot:

### [image: screenshot]

In my code I added `<CreatePatient>` (it's a modal window and it's hidden) only into `PatientsToolbar`, but in vue-devtools I see this tag also at the bottom.

What such behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: Please include the the HTML/javascript that replicates this issue.

Comment: It's difficult because I'm using webpack for build. May be this issue appears because I'm using UIkit with Vue. Template of the `CreatePatient` has modal component of UIkit. And may be UIKit's javascript affects on the DOM and that we see in vue-devtools.